# use github with yubikey without phone

Tags: github, two-factor-authentication, yubikey

I am using Xubuntu 18.04 and wonder if there is a way to use Two-factor authentication with github but without a phone. Currently I need to enter the verification number that is shown on my phone/nfc/yubikey when logging in to github. I would like to use the yubikey via usb on my laptop, is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

ok I did not see it in the first wizard, but its just called "security keys" in github account security https://github.com/settings/security